# Matching digits from text in R using regex with \d in character group

Tags: r, regex

I have what should be a simple problem, finding chapter headings in a text, and have found one solution, but can't see why an alternative regex doesn't give the correct answer.

So here's a toy example, followed by a regex which finds the first item, and another that finds them all.

```
chapters <- c("chapter 1", "chapter I", "chapter iv")

grep("^chapter //d", chapters, ignore.case=T)

grep("^chapter (\\d|i|v)", chapters, ignore.case=T)
```

What I don't understand is why, however, the following code only finds the second and third items when putting items in a character goup [] means they are alternatives:

```
grep("^chapter [\\div]", chapters, ignore.case=T)
```

What's wrong with the last regex? I'm sorry if this seems basic - I've written far more complex regex expressions than this last one before, and am baffled as to what is going on....

Thank you.

Comment: If you add `perl = TRUE`, it should work. Your first example with `//d` is actually wrong.

Comment: Using `0-9` instead of `\\d` works too. `grep("^chapter [0-9iv]", chapters, ignore.case=T)`

Answer (score 1):

In a character group, `\\d` is evaluated differently here. It actually becomes "match either a literal backslash or the character d". So

```
grep("^chapter [\\div]", chapters, ignore.case=T)
```

would e.g. match `chapter \` or `chapter d`.

To overcome this you can do one of the following:

```
grep("^chapter [[:digit:]iv]", chapters, ignore.case=T)

grep("^chapter [0-9iv]", chapters, ignore.case=T)

grep("^chapter [\\div]", chapters, ignore.case=T, perl=T)
```

[Test it yourself here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/9OzdQdg)